# What is the framework and concise definition of the New Perspective on Paul?

Tags: paul-apostle, npp

Can you list a simple matrix of the old and new views on the Perspective on Paul from the viewpoint of vetted and at least modestly accepted details based on the New Perspective of Paul?

I'm not as interested at this time on the arguments for or against the New Perspective, but simply a list of the main topics (vetted to some extent) of what the new perspectives are and what the old perspective was.

I understand that the Old Perspectives probably have different viewpoints as well, please consider using the basic United States Protestant perspective (probably based on Martin Luther's work) or just leave the "Old Perspective" empty and I'll infer it from my own reading.

Conceptually what are the hinges of the NPP viewpoint on which the interpretation of the writings of Paul swings?

Define the hinges, ignore the position of the door so to speak.

Comment: First, are the "hinges" you speak of the basic assumptions (or presuppositions) of the NPP? Second, are you interested in knowing how the NPP conflicts with the OPP? In other words, is your question, "The NPP and the OPP are at odds with one another over the issues of _____________ and these are the assumptions and key terms which cause them to be at odds": ________________ (fill in the blank)? Don

Comment: That seems to more succinctly restate my question.  is it worth doing a drastic edit?

Comment: Not necessarily. Maybe I'll take a stab at making a few judicious edits, simply to clarify your question.

Comment: See also [What is “new” in the New Perspective on Paul?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4706/30)

Comment: What is it about this question that is different from Caleb's?

Comment: The only real difference I see is I'm looking for more brevity with a focus on the actual paradigm shift.  The referenced answer gives a great summary and explanation of the topic.  I'm asking for direct explicit summary of the differing points of view on Paul, not an overall review of the topic at large.

Answer (score -1):

The Hinge on the New Perspective of Paul Rests mainly on the new 15th century  understanding or reformers that Old Covenant Judaism was a “works based salvation.” The ‘New Perspective on Paul’, which is a protestant new prospective on how to understand the writings of the Evangelist Paul, who was a hightly learned Rabbi, understood the Old Covenant Judaism as one of Grace 1st, then Faith, through Circumcision and obedience to the ordinances of the Law to stay in that covenantal Relationship.

The works of E.P. Sanders "Paul and Palestinian Judaism" Comments of and relating to Covenantal Nomism. That Judaism
 Was a Grace based Covenant and that to enter into it one must be circumcised, pass on their faith to their heirs and do the works associated with the covenant to stay in covenant"

> E.P. Sanders “Covenantal nomism, in opposition to merit theology, is the belief that 1st century Jews in the land of Israel did not believe in works righteousness. Essentially, it is the belief that one is brought into the Abrahamic covenant through birth and stays in the covenant through works.”   Source wiki.  Also E.P. Sanders work  “Paul and Palestinian Judaism”

The realization that Paul was not speaking against all works but simply works of the Law is at the heart of New Pauline Perspective. It is plain (to those who fallow the new perspective) when understood in its historical context, that the reformers turned upside down the orthodox teachings of the church, reformers, who were rightly looking for reforms within the Catholic Church, made mistakes in their interpretations.  Abandoning the reality of who Saint Paul was, and the world he lived in, in unity by necessity of revolting, the sacred teachings preserved by the Church, and under the pressures of secular powers challenged and apposed by virtue of theses misconceptions, those sacred teachings were abandoned. Reforms were made within the church however that did not abandon the original interpretations.

> ling for reformation inside the Church
>   http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/04437a.htm

The Framework of the New Perspective on Paul it that in opposition to the OLD Framework (Protestant) that Salvation in OLD Covenant Judaism was works based identifies that belief to be a false assumption and that Old Covenant Judaism is in fact and always has been, Grace Based, faith based and Obedience based.

In addition to this perspective which is a direct assault on precepts of the reformation, the new perspective on Paul suggests that Saint Paul, being a Jew with a 1st Century Jewish mentality, understood that you must enter into the New Covenant, Maintain your covenantal commitment, and remain in covenant in order to be Saved.

Comment: I was unable to make changes to deleted answer.  I enter this for submission.  I beleive this response does answer the question.  Protestants who do not adhere to the New Prospective, this answer is sure to leave a bitter taste in their mouths.  The validity of my answer is in line with the question.

Comment: The reformers did not believe that "Old Covenant Judaism" was works-based salvation.  If you are thinking of "the covenant of works," that's something else entirely.

Comment: Phrases like "false understanding" are not welcome here. Explain the differing viewpoints, but do so objectively, without interjecting polemic or disparaging viewpoints with which you disagree. It's fine to state your opinion, but do so as such ("However in my opinion, X is the case...), and do it politely.

Comment: @flimzy I reworded it again so no to offend